# How to trigger click event on a bar in Flot Stacked Bar Chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, stacked-chart

I wanted to trigger the click event of the lowest bar of the first stacked bar in Flot.

The rationale for this is that I wanted to select this portion of the chart on first load and at the same time execute the onClick handler of the bar.

I know that jQuery supports this behavior but I just don't know how to integrate it with Flot.

How can it be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using flot charts or jqWidgets charts (jqxChart)?  The question title says jqWidgets but it's tagged flot...

Comment: I'm not using jQWidgets Chart. I'm using Flot Charts. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to trigger a plotclick event on the desired column's point passing the trigger the appropriate `item`.

For instance, say you want to click the 4th column of the first series:

```
var col = 4; // 4th column
var series = somePlot.getData()[0]; // first series
var dataIndex = col - 1;
ps = series.datapoints.pointsize;
var item = {
  datapoint: series.datapoints.points.slice(dataIndex * ps, (dataIndex + 1) * ps),
  dataIndex: dataIndex,
  series: series,
  seriesIndex: 0
};
$('#placeholder').trigger('plotclick',  [ null, item ]); // passing a null position, we don't need it
```

This will in turn call your plotclick event

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
  if (item) {
     somePlot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
  }
});
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9ceSDFuKLMM7awAd84Ru?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

To trigger click events in the [jQWidgets Chart](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm?(arctic)) (jqxChart), you can look at: [Chart Events](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/javascript_chart_events.htm?arctic)